# How do I invite a user to chat and mentioning user?

Tags: support, chat

I had thought to chat with a specific user, but I don't see any way to invite anyone to chat, and I am wondering if using the @username formulation will cause a notification to appear in a user's notification queue?

Comment: Here's something to try. If they've *ever* posted in a chat room, click on the user name - if it's not already a link, there's an option to open a chat room with them. If you try it, please comment here on whether it pinged them as part of the process.

Answer (score 3):

If you create a chat room you can invite a user to it. The limitation is that the user has to have used chat before, in order that they have a chat user to invite.

First of all you have to find the user you want to invite.

- visit the [chat.se users tab](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users)
- type in the name of the user you want to invite:
  [image: SE chat search, users' tab.]
- select that user by clicking on their name

Then you need to create a room for you both:
[image: Chat user page, hilighting chat room creation button]

Then an invitation is sent by the system to that user, which appears in their SE inbox, like comment pings do.

Comment: Hello, you called?